# MVC Moving data through views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm wonder what is the recommended best practice for passing data through views as you build a table to insert into a database?

So for example, if you had an employee web app where the first page you enter details for the new employee, first and second name.  The second page you enter the department details.

You use two different models for this for validation etc.

So when you update the name model, and redirect to the second page view, how can you pass the data there, store it while you update the department data and then either update a combined model and or pass to a third view to enter say contact details for a third view.

I can see it possible by passing viewbag data but this looks scrappy.  The issue I have is only being able to reference one model per view so it seems to be dropping the previous data.

```
namespace Next.Controllers
{
    public class NextController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Next
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult NewEmpFirst()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult NewEmpFirst([Bind(Include = "ID, Forename, Surname")] First NewEmpFirst)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                First first = new First
                {
                    ID = 1,
                    Forename = NewEmpFirst.Forename,
                    Surname = NewEmpFirst.Surname
                };
            }

            TempData["first"] = NewEmpFirst;
            return RedirectToAction("NewEmpSecond");
        }

        public ActionResult NewEmpSecond()
        {
            First first = TempData["first"] as First;
            TempData["first"] = first;
            ViewBag.Forename = first.Forename;


            return View(); 
        }


        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult NewEmpSecond([Bind(Include = "ID, Department")] Second NewEmpSecond)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                First first = TempData["first"] as First;

                FirstSecond fs = new FirstSecond
                {
                    ID = 1,
                    Forename = first.Forename,
                    Surname = first.Surname,
                    Department = "hello"
                };
            }

            TempData["fs"] = NewEmpSecond;
            return RedirectToAction("NewEmpThird");
        }

        public ActionResult NewEmpThird()
        {
            FirstSecond fs = TempData["fs"] as FirstSecond;

            return View(fs);
        }

    }
}
```

What I have so far.  The data will pass from one view to another but when I reference a different model to have that data inserted then it just seems to empty the previous set of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use session variables. Better yet, you can create a class that will have all the properties you need to collect and keep an instance of that class as a session variable. Once you reach the last step of your process, get the saved instance and save it to the database.

i.e the class to store values could look like this:

```
public class MySessionValues
{
    public First Employee;
    public Second Department;

    // other steps here ...
}
```

Then in your controller action `NewEmpFirst` use it instead of `Temp`

```
var sessionValues = new MySessionValues();
sessionValues.Employee = first;
Session["MySessionValues"] = sessionValues;
```

In later steps retrieve the saved instance and add new values:

```
var sessionValues = Session["MySessionValues"] as MySessionValues;
sessionValues.Second = NewEmpSecond; // or any other value you're saving
Session["MySessionValues"] = sessionValues;
```

You see the pattern. You could also create methods on `MySessionValues` class that would help with storing and retrieving the instance from the `Session` scope.

You can place the class in a file in the `App_Code` folder if you want, or create `Helpers` folder in the root of your app (same level as `Controllers`folder). However, if you're only using this class in that one controller, you can put the code in the same file as your controller.

Comment: By creating a class, do you mean have id, forename, surname and department in one class and add forename and surname in one session and department in another?

If so that wont work as I want to have validation on some of them as being required fields.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this now.

Edit

Where is best to create this class, in the Controllers folder or App_Code?  Is there a recommended convention for this?

Comment: Sorry I can't give you rep yet, thanks for the solution, works a treat I have learnt something very useful!